# Найти аргумент в функции, принимающей динамическое количество аргументов

Tags: javascript

Имеется функция, например:

```
function example(...args) {
     //make smth
}
```

Среди аргументов передается объект, у которого имеется поле timeout, есть ли какие-либо элегантные решения этой задачи, кроме перебора аргументов, думал насчет копирования аргументов в объект и обращение к его свойствам, однако, не придумал как избавиться красиво от вложенности:

```
const obj = {...args};
```

Comment: нет, никакого решения кроме перебора нет.

Comment: @Grundy а как же там, люмус-максима, авада-кедавра, экспелиармус и аргументус-экстрактус? :D

Comment: @teran, Только перебор, только хардкор!

Comment: Объект постоянно передается?

Comment: @РустамГимранов да